# Hidden command window, STARTUPINFO and global name 'subprocess' not defined

Tags: python, windows, command-line, import, subprocess

I've been working on creating GUI front ends for command line programs and all the help I've gotten here has been amazing.  I can never thank you guys enough.

Here's a test program I've been working on that displays the contents of a .CAB file in Windows:

```
#!python2.7

import sys
import os
from tkFileDialog import *
from subprocess import *
from Tkinter import *

def getfilename():
    blankline = 0 # counter to help remove blank lines
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All files","*"), ("Cab files","*.cab")]) # get the filename
    if filename == "": # if the user hits the Cancel button, don't change anything in the list box
        return
    listbox.delete(0, END) # clear the list box
    numberinlist = 0 # count the number of lines in the list box to delete the extra blank line at the end of the list
    if os.name == 'nt': # send the command without opening a command window
        start_info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        start_info.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    commandline = Popen(['expand', '-D', filename], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, startupinfo=start_info)
    # commend the above 4 lines and uncomment the below line and the program works but opens a command window
    #commandline = Popen(['expand', '-D', filename], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    while True: # read expand.exe's output and strip undeeded characters at the end of each line
        listboxline = commandline.stdout.readline().rstrip()
        listbox.insert(END, listboxline)
        numberinlist += 1
        if len(listboxline) ==0: # check for blank lines
            blankline += 1
            if blankline == 3: # expand.exe sends an extra three blank lines, see if it's the third blank line
                listbox.delete(numberinlist - 1) # if it is the third blank line remove the extra line at the end
                break # quit the while loop, expand.exe is finished after the third blank line

# set up the window    
mywindow = Tk()
mywindow.geometry('400x400')

# add a frame to position the list box in
frame1 = Frame(mywindow)
frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# name the scroll bars
vertscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame1, orient=VERTICAL)
horzscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame1, orient=HORIZONTAL)

# name the list box and attach the scroll bars
listbox = Listbox(frame1, selectmode=EXTENDED, yscrollcommand=vertscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=horzscrollbar.set)
vertscrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
horzscrollbar.config(command=listbox.xview)

# create the scroll bars and list box
vertscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
horzscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# add another frame to position the button in
frame2 = Frame(mywindow)
frame2.pack(fill=X)

# create the button and tell it to go to the getfilename function when clicked
filebutton = Button(frame2, text="Open cab file", command=getfilename)
filebutton.pack()

# start the GUI
mywindow.mainloop()
```

I've added lots of comments so if someone is searching for the answer to a different problem they might find the answer in this program example.  The idea is to display the results of 'expand.exe -D' line by line into a list box without having the Windows, command line, shell window pop-up, instead keeping it in the background.  As you can see from the first line (shebang) I'm using Python 2.7.  The problem I'm having is I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Python\2.7\listcab.pyw", line 17, in getfilename
    start_info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not defined
```

I've been searching stackoverflow and Google for this error but I've been unable to find anything.  I'm sure it's a simple problem with my import list but I have no idea what it is.  I still don't fully understand Python's different import commands, which to use, when to use them and what the difference between them is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you used a star import...

```
from subprocess import *
```

you shouldn't be prefixing things you imported from it:

```
subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
```

should actually be just...

```
STARTUPINFO()
```

---

If you want to use prefixes, you'd want to just do...

```
import subprocess
```

which instead of importing all of the names from `subprocess` into the global namespace, just imports `subprocess` itself, letting you then use its names with the prefix.

Then you'd use things like `subprocess.Popen()`, `subprocess.STARTUPINFO()`, et cetera.

This is generally considered the preferred way to do imports; it avoids name collisions if two different modules have similarly named functions, and makes it clearer where things came from.

Comment: I changed `from subprocess import *` to `import subprocess` and `commandline = Popen(['expand', '-D', filename], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, startupinfo=start_info)` to `commandline = subprocess.Popen(['expand', '-D', filename], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, startupinfo=start_info)`  It worked!!

Comment: What you're saying is if I just use `from subprocess import *` I should be able to remove all prefixes of `subprocess.`, but when I do, I get the same error.

Comment: Oh, I also changed `start_info.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` to `start_info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`